# Adding Numeric Range Filtering to ActiveAdmin

Tags: activeadmin, formtastic, ransack, numeric-ranges

Greetings and Happy Holidays 2015 --

I tried to add numeric range filtering per the excellent blog post by [Boris Stall](http://staal.io/blog/2013/02/26/mastering-activeadmin/).

I'm running:

- Rails 4.2.4
- Ruby 2.2.3
- ActiveAdmin 1.0.0pre2

I keep running into this error:

> Unable to find input class NumericRangeInput

Here is my config/initializers/active_admin/filter_numeric_range_input.rb

```
module ActiveAdmin
  module Inputs
    class FilterNumericRangeInput < ::Formtastic::Inputs::StringInput # Add filter module wrapper
      include ActiveAdmin::Inputs::Filters::Base

      def to_html
        input_wrapping do
          [ label_html,
            builder.text_field(gt_input_name, input_html_options(gt_input_name)),
            template.content_tag(:span, "-", :class => "seperator"),
            builder.text_field(lt_input_name, input_html_options(lt_input_name)),
          ].join("\n").html_safe
        end
      end

      def gt_input_name
        "#{method}_gteq"
      end
      alias :input_name :gt_input_name

      def lt_input_name
        "#{method}_lteq"
      end

      def input_html_options(input_name = gt_input_name)
        current_value = @object.send(input_name)
         { :size => 10, :id => "#{input_name}_numeric" , :value => current_value }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I'm simply trying:

```
filter :id, as: :numeric_range
```

I've researched the potential issues integrating AA, Ransack, Formtastic, etc., but I'm not advanced enough to know where to go from here.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It seems newer versions of ActiveAdmin might have a different strategy for loading or naming other classes in the input module. I noticed that the class name in the file is called `FilterNumericRangeInput`. So AA must be doing something to convert the name, we just need to figure out which symbol to give to convert properly. So as an experiment, I tried to rename the symbol in `app/admin/test.rb` to:

```
filter :id, as: :numeric_range_2
```

And I got the error:

```
Unable to find input class NumericRange2Input
```

So with that hint I tried changing the symbol name to:

```
filter :id, as: :filter_numeric_range
```

And it worked.

Comment: As a follow-up, later on I renamed the class itself to `NumericRangeInput` because I noticed the CSS classes being generated were called `filter_filter_numeric_range`, and that bugged me so I renamed the class then used it as `filter :id, as: numeric_range`

Comment: this worked like a charm.  I had a hunch it was a naming issue but was not sure where to try the changes.  Thanks a million for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

At this point you just need `filter :id, as: :numeric`

Comment: this does not filter range, it only gives "greater than, equals, less than" dropdown menu.